# dimnames and sapply - how to change value in .GlobalEnv

Tags: r

I have a stupid question. For example, I have code like this:

```
resultNorm <- lapply(2:5, function(numBeans) { parSapply(cl, 1:iterations, GetBinsNormDistribs, numBeans = numBeans) });
```

So, I have list which consists data like this:

```
> resultNorm 
[[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2246621 0.09398241 0.1356241
[2,] 0.3107575 0.05482151 0.1331455
[3,] 0.9261597 0.77957860 0.8280028
[4,] 1.2077192 1.17804615 1.0985935

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.04151756 0.07737258 0.06166794
[2,] 0.04680101 0.07138281 0.07005758
[3,] 0.98120583 0.96825317 0.96955009
[4,] 1.52177642 1.57192003 1.62818979

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.1151765 0.1733337 0.07806343
[2,] 0.1405760 0.2070153 0.07304057
[3,] 0.8228107 0.9457689 1.03273787
[4,] 1.6026743 1.7581600 1.89761473

[[4]]
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
[1,] 0.1360939 0.1590460 0.08682901
[2,] 0.1520694 0.2047105 0.07762287
[3,] 0.9121020 1.0151550 0.96390948
[4,] 1.9088521 2.0688248 1.99595126
```

So, I want to use `dimnames` for this list and give each row unique name:
I tried code like this, but without any result:

```
devNull <- sapply(1:length(resultNorm), function(i, envir = .GlobalEnv) { dimnames(resultNorm[[i]]) <- list(c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4")) })
```

`resultNorm` doesn't have any changes... 
Could you tell me, how to work with `sapply` and `.GlobalEnv` data?

I want to get an output like this:

```
> resultNorm 
[[1]]
          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
a1 0.2246621 0.09398241 0.1356241
a2 0.3107575 0.05482151 0.1331455
a3 0.9261597 0.77957860 0.8280028
a4 1.2077192 1.17804615 1.0985935

[[2]]
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
a1 0.04151756 0.07737258 0.06166794
a2 0.04680101 0.07138281 0.07005758
a3 0.98120583 0.96825317 0.96955009
a4 1.52177642 1.57192003 1.62818979

[[3]]
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
a1 0.1151765 0.1733337 0.07806343
a2 0.1405760 0.2070153 0.07304057
a3 0.8228107 0.9457689 1.03273787
a4 1.6026743 1.7581600 1.89761473

[[4]]
          [,1]      [,2]       [,3]
a1 0.1360939 0.1590460 0.08682901
a2 0.1520694 0.2047105 0.07762287
a3 0.9121020 1.0151550 0.96390948
a4 1.9088521 2.0688248 1.99595126
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: This is not a MWE. Please turn it into one.

Comment: @docendo discimus Added into the main text.

Comment: @Pascal, sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `lapply(resultNorm, function(mat) {rownames(mat) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"); mat})`

Comment: Minimal Working Example.

Comment: @Roland, thanks, this is one I really want!

Comment: Better to do it right the first time, `fun = function(i, ...) { result <- GetBinNormsDistribs(i, ...); rownames(result) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4"); result }` then use `fun` instead of `GetBinNormsDistribs` in your `parLapply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to set the rownames of matrices inside a list:

```
lapply(resultNorm, #loop over the list elements instead of over an index
         function(mat) {
           rownames(mat) <- c("a1", "a2", "a3", "a4") #assign rownames
           mat})
```